# State matrix depends on control input

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory, optimal-control

I have a state space system that I want to apply LQR to, however, the parameters of the time varying state matrix ($\mathbf{A}(t)$) depend on the input vector ($\mathbf{u}(t)$). Are there any known workarounds for this situation? Something like introducing delay or a change of variables? I've written out the equation below:

$$
x(t+1) = \big[(1-u(t)w)^2 \big]x(t) + \big[w u(t) \big]u(t)$$

$w$ is just a constant. $u(t)$ and $x(t)$ are always positive.

Comment: What you describe is nonlinear behavior, so the linear part of Linear Quadratic Regular does not hold. For nonlinear systems one can sometimes do some tricks to make it look linear, but that really depends on the nonlinearity. So could you add more details to your question about how exactly $A(t)$ is a function of $u(t)$?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Ah, I see. Sorry, I've went ahead and included it.

Comment: What is $w$? Is there any other property for the system? The input?

Comment: It's just a constant

Comment: And the other questions?

Comment: u(t) is always positive, but I'm not aware of any other properties to exploit sadly

Comment: You should have provided all those details in the post in order to gave a self-contained question and avoid so much back and forth.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I will do better in the future

Comment: No problem. Is the state positive?

Comment: Sorry, I had to go check to see if it was. Yes, I believe it is too.

Comment: Ok, that will not be easy and there may not be any closed-form solution as for most optimal control problems. But there is always the possibility for numerical methods such direct approaches to optimal control or model predictive control.